# python pandas merge pivot tables

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pivot

I created 9 pivot tables:

they all look like this

```
          2015
NR_V    
  0    20.000000
  1    20.405677
  2    35.982625
  3    50.475167
  4    61.578472
```

I want to merge them all by NR_V the way I would merge normal tables, but I think that empty line is throwing it off.

I tried this

```
dfs = [p_2009, p_2010, p_2011, p_2012, p_2013, p_2014, p_2015 ]
merge = partial(pd.merge, on=['NR_V'], how='outer')

result = dfs[0]
     for df in dfs[1:]:
     result = merge(result, df)
```

But I get an error "KeyError: 'NR_V'".

Comment: What's your expected result in terms of format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
dfs = [p_2009, p_2010, p_2011, p_2012, p_2013, p_2014, p_2015 ]
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

[image]

---

***response to comment***
If you want to get rid of empty space

```
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: It worked - thank you! Do you know a way of getting rid of that empty row and moving up NR_V to be in one row with the years?